# How to add html file into different js folder

Tags: javascript, html

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubNMr.png)
I want to add html file in my js, and this pic is the path in my directory. How can I do?

in my config.js, I widh to include my file as `let ADDR_iframe1 = "../templates/switch.html";`

Comment: Your question really doesn't make a lot of sense. Please provide much more detail about the problem. (Aside from anything else your directory structure implies that `switch.html` is a template file used by **server side** code and that the JS file is **client side** JS which wouldn't have access to the template at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript fetch() Method to Load an External HTML File.
Please find the below example for your reference.

```
function loadHTML() {

    fetch('switch.html')

   .then(response=> response.text())

   .then(text=> document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = text);

}
```